# Load DLL at runtime in PHP

Tags: php, dll

IS there any way to load a *.dll file at run time into PHP project.
For instance I want to use the functionality for encrypting the a string using MCRYPT module without installing the module.

I found on internet that with the usage of COM class I can achieve this but don't know how implement this.

Comment: have you checked [dl](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php)?

Comment: This function is already removed from PHP 5.4